# getting flexbox (via Vuetify) to align column content to the right

Tags: css, flexbox, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create list items in Vuetify consisting of `v-row`s containing 3 `v-col`, where the third column contains a checkbox.  Here's my current code for the list items:

```
   <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="item.value"  class="ma-0 pa-0">
      <div class="ma-0 pa-0 pr-2 pl-2">
        <v-row class="d-flex" style="flex-direction:row" fill-height>
          <v-col class="handle d-flex align-center" cols="12" md="2">
            <v-icon>mdi-drag</v-icon>
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="d-flex  align-center"   cols="12" md="8">{{ item.text }}
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="d-flex align-right" cols="12" md="2">
              <v-checkbox  class="d-flex" @change="handleToggle(index)" :input-value="item.show">
              </v-checkbox>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </div>
```

And this ends up looking like:

[image]

How can I get the checkbox to align to the right, so they are vertically aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `d-flex` class to the `div` that is wrapping the `<v-row>` and add `width: 100%` to the style. Then, add specific width to the parent of `v-list-item` so it won't fill up the page.

```html
<v-list style="width: 400px;">  <!-- Add specific width to the parent -->

  <v-list-item ... >
     <div class="... d-flex" style="width: 100%">  <!-- Add d-flex and width: 100% here -->
       <v-row ... >
         <v-col ... >...</v-col>
         <v-col ... >...</v-col>
         <v-col ... >...</v-col>
       </v-row>
     </div>
  </v-list-tem>

</v-list>
```

[image]

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-wing-rx8yd?file=/src/components/Playground.vue).